# Problem loading urdf in rviz (groovy)

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow urdf tutorials at http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch and in the very first step I'm having difficulties to load the urdf model in rviz. As suggested by tutorial, I run the command:

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf
```

Running this line, an empty rviz scene is opened like the image below:

http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/5176/screenshot20130211at315.png

Just in case, here is the contents of the urdf.vcg file:

```
Background\ ColorR=0.0941176
Background\ ColorG=0
Background\ ColorB=0.466667
Fixed\ Frame=/base_link
Target\ Frame=<Fixed Frame>
Grid.Alpha=0.5
Grid.Cell\ Size=0.5
Grid.ColorR=0.898039
Grid.ColorG=0.898039
Grid.ColorB=0.898039
Grid.Enabled=1
Grid.Line\ Style=0
Grid.Line\ Width=0.03
Grid.Normal\ Cell\ Count=0
Grid.OffsetX=0
Grid.OffsetY=0
Grid.OffsetZ=0
Grid.Plane=0
Grid.Plane\ Cell\ Count=10
Grid.Reference\ Frame=<Fixed Frame>
Robot\ Model.Alpha=1
Robot\ Model.Collision\ Enabled=0
Robot\ Model.Enabled=1
Robot\ Model.Robot\ Description=robot_description
Robot\ Model.TF\ Prefix=
Robot\ Model.Update\ Interval=0
Robot\ Model.Visual\ Enabled=1
Robot\:\ Robot\ Model\ Link\ base_linkShow\ Axes=0
Robot\:\ Robot\ Model\ Link\ base_linkShow\ Trail=0
Robot\:\ Robot\ Model\ Link\ legShow\ Axes=0
Robot\:\ Robot\ Model\ Link\ legShow\ Trail=0
Tool\ 2D\ Nav\ GoalTopic=goal
Tool\ 2D\ Pose\ EstimateTopic=initialpose
Camera\ Type=rviz::OrbitViewController
Camera\ Config=1.15779 3.76081 2.16475 0 0 0
Property\ Grid\ State=selection=.Global StatusTopStatus;expanded=.Global Options,Grid.Enabled,Robot Model.Enabled;scrollpos=0,0;splitterpos=150,285;ispageselected=1
[Display0]
Name=Grid
Package=rviz
ClassName=rviz::GridDisplay
[Display1]
Name=Robot Model
Package=rviz
ClassName=rviz::RobotModelDisplay
```

P.S. Running the command above, generates no error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54916/problem-loading-urdf-in-rviz-(groovy)/) by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-06-25**:
Can you show the content of display.launch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is similar to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/60888/urdf_tutorial-groovy-vs-fuerte/)

A [recent patch by Shaun Edwards](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robot_model_tutorials/blob/master/urdf_tutorial/urdf.rviz) adds a Groovy compatible config file.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-06-25**:
Note that the current ros-groovy-urdf-tutorial package includes this fix.  So, if you're using groovy, you can probably just update your debian packages, and the tutorial should work.  Otherwise, you can download the latest urdf_tutorial package source to your ROS package path.  No compiling req'd!